# How many virtual processors can be assign to virtual machines in Hyper-V manager

Tags: virtualization, hyper-v, processor

can you easily explain, how many virtual processors I can assign to virtual machines in Hyper-V manager?

Example:

I have computer with 4 cores and 8 logical processors. I have created 4 virtual machines.

Can I only assign 2 virtual processors per virtual machine ?

It will be 2+2+2+2 = 8

Or can I assign 8 virtual processors per virtual machine ?

It will be 8+8+8+8 = 32

Thank you in advance.

Comment: "Can I only ...", did you try it out? I'm pretty sure the manager will easily tell you whether you can do something or not.

Comment: Yes, I try it. Hyper-V manager allows me to add 64 CPUs per machine. Do you think it's okay?